# Cleaning up a .bib file

Tags: bibtex

I have a large `.bib` file which is in a mess. In particular:

1. Entries are not in any particular order.
2. Some entries may be duplicates (albeit with different keys).
3. Some entries may not be used in the relevant book.

(1
 is an issue because I'm working through the `.bib` file fixing up items one by one and examining the corresponding changes in the book; at the moment I'm having to dart back and forth a lot.

3 is an issue because I need to check the correctness of each entry manually, which can take a while; thus unused entries mean a lot of wasted time.)

Is there a way of taking a `.bib` file and cleaning it up?  In particular, I'd like to

a) create a `.bib` file which is sorted by author, and

b) delete or, better, comment out unused entries.

Comment: Open your `.bib` file with JabRef and it will complain about duplicates if you search for them from some menu option that I don't remember at the moment. Then also you can sort it as you wish by clicking the columns etc.

Comment: I think the [`checkcites`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites) script might help, at least for listing the unused entries. The script analyzes both `.aux` and `.bib` files; in order to list only unused references in your `.bib` file, use `$ checkcites --unused mydoc.aux` in the command line. `:)` Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of the script.

Comment: I would use some program to manage your `.bib` entries. BibDesk om mac or see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9454/bibdesk-like-software-for-windows

Comment: JabRef works beautifully -- thank you. If you turn it into an answer, I will accept it. (I didn't try checkcites as JabRef made it easy enough to detect unused entries -- but thanks for the suggestion.)

Comment: Mohan, just for your information: When you start a comment with "AT username", for example AT percusse, that user will get notified of your post. It is not necessary to use AT OriginalPoster, here AT Mohan, because the original poster of a question or of an answer gets notified automatically. (Replace AT by @ - only one @ allowed per post...)

Comment: @percusse: There is a comment for you above (without @percusse).

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for the remainder. I've put the details into Boris answer as I didn't know about bibexport which is a nice tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file)

Comment: @AugustJanse only a partial duplicate I think (only answers question #3 here).

Comment: I'd like to note another tool I stumbled upon in another thread about merging. It is capable of basically everything I needed, just in browser: See https://github.com/FlamingTempura/bibtex-tidy and credit for the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651649 .

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I would recommend [bibexport](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibexport) script.  It creates a new `.bib` file that includes only the references you cite in the `.tex` file, and cleans them up.  I use it for submissions to journals, when I want to send only the relevant references rather than my databases.

---

Also [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) has some duplicate search and resolve capabilities which can be accessed via the menu items shown (for v2.8) below:

[image]

Comment: How nice! I didn't know about `bibexport`, thanks! `:)`

Comment: I've added the JabRef details to your answer since a standalone JabRef answer would make a little contribution. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Surely.  I've never used JabRef myself, but people praise it.

Comment: JabRef offers a feature similar to `bibexport`: _Tools > New Subdatabase based on AUX file_. This, however, seems to work only with bibtex but not biblatex (I might be wrong here, it didn't work when I checked on my files, but I didn't check in detail why).

Comment: It's worth noting that `bibexport`, and I think the other solutions that are being mentioned, won't work if you're using BibLaTeX because they rely on parsing .aux files. I've had a go at writing something that parses .bcf files, but it's very rough and ready: [github.com/twsh/Bibliography-extraction](https://github.com/twsh/Bibliography-extraction).

Comment: The JabRef solution "New Subdatabase based on AUX file" with pictures: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212133/11816

Comment: The JabRef duplicate resolver still requires you to click through potentially hundreds of boxes to manually select the entry to keep per set of duplicates

Comment: I agree.  I was approached by some people who want a standalone tool to do this; maybe I will write one.

Answer (score 15):

This is a python code that automatically deal with some of these issues. Please feel free to give feedback or suggestions to enhance or extend the features of this code. Hope it can help.

```py
# perform some tests on ped.bib related to the pdf-directory (pdfdir)
# activate one or more tests by setting those control variables to 1

# 1. is_check_file: check objects with no or empty file entry
# 2. is_check_double_file: check if two or more different objects have the same pdf entry
# 3. is_check_unused_files: check <pdfdir> for unsused files

import os, sys, glob, copy
from os import path, access, R_OK  # W_OK for write permission.
from operator import itemgetter

#-------- control parameter ---------
is_check_file = 0
is_check_double_file = 0
is_check_unused_files = 1
#------------------------------------   

ROOT = os.getenv("HOME") # Home directory
#ROOT = path.expanduser("~") # works on all platforms  

pdfdir = ROOT + '/lit/pdf/'
print 'pdfdir', pdfdir
debug = 0 # shutdown debug/info messages

bib_data = open('ped.bib')

words = ['author', 'title', 'journal', 'year', 'volume', 'comment', 'issue', 'owner', 'file', 'timestamp', 'booktitle', 'editor', 'publisher', 'number', 'part', 'keywords', 'doi', 'month', 'organization', 'url']
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def check_missing_pdf(element):
    """
    following testes:
    1. element has no file entry
    2. element has empty file entry
    3. element has file entry with inexistant pdf-file
    """
    #check missing files
    if not element.has_key('file'): # element has no file
        print >>sys.stderr, '==== %s has no file entry'%element.get('key')
    elif not element.get('file'):  # .. or file is empty
            print >>sys.stderr, '**** %s has empty file entry'%element.get('key')
    else:
        # we have a file entry -----> check its existance in the pdf dir
        pdffile = pdfdir + element.get('file')
        if not( path.exists(pdffile) and path.isfile(pdffile) and access(pdffile, R_OK)):
            print >>sys.stderr, '#### %s with file entry [%s]: Either file is missing or is not readable'%(element.get('key'), element.get('file'))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def check_doubles(elements):
    """
    check if two or more different objects have the same pdf-file 
    """
    doubles = {}
    for element in elements:
        pdffile = element.get("file")
        key = element.get("key")
        if not doubles.has_key(pdffile):
            doubles[pdffile] = [key]
        else:
            doubles[pdffile].append(key)
    for f, k in doubles.iteritems():
        if f and len(k) > 1: # if f excludes case f == None
            print >>sys.stderr, "Keys:", k, "have the same file <%s>"%f
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def check_unused_files(elements):
    """
    check dir pdfdir ("lit/pdf") for pdf-files that are not used
    in the ped.bib
    """
    pdf_files = glob.glob( pdfdir + "*.pdf") # pdfs in lit/pdf/
    dummy_files = copy.copy(pdf_files) # list of unused files
    for pdf in pdf_files:
        for element in elements:
            element_pdf =  element.get("file")
            if element_pdf is None:
                continue
            element_pdf = path.basename(element_pdf)

            if path.basename(pdf) == element_pdf:
                dummy_files.remove(pdf)
                break # check next files

    if dummy_files:
        print >>sys.stderr, "%d files are not used:"%len(dummy_files)
        for f in dummy_files:
            print >>sys.stderr, "---->",path.basename(f)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def putWord(string, dic, line):
    """
    extract from <line> the value of the key <string> and put it in  <dic>
    """
    tmp = line[1].strip(' { } , .').split(':')
    # some files are like this :llll:aaaa. So tmp[0] is here == ''
    if not tmp[0]: 
        dic[string] = tmp[1]
    else:
        dic[string] = tmp[0]
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def getElement(f):
    """
    get ONE element from file f.
    return dict
    """
    dic = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip(' \n\r')
        if not line:
            continue
        #get <key> and <type>
        if line[0] == '@':
            sline = line.split('{')
            typ = sline[0][1:]
            if typ == 'comment': # ignore jabref-meta
                continue
            dic['type'] = typ.strip(',') 
            key = sline[1].strip(',')
            if debug:
                print >> sys.stderr, '--------> type: <%s>'%typ
                print >> sys.stderr, '--------> key: <%s>'%key
            dic['key'] = key

        line = line.split('=')

        for word in words:
            if line[0].strip(' ') == word:
                putWord(word, dic, line)
                if debug:
                    print  >> sys.stderr, '--------> %s: <%s>'%(word, line[1].strip(' { },.') ) 

        # check for last line of element
        if line[0] == '}':
            if debug:
                print >> sys.stderr, '---------------------------------'
            return dic
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#----------------------- get content of file in elements ------------------------------
elements = []
while True:
    dic = getElement(bib_data) 
    if not dic:
        sorted(elements, key=itemgetter('key')) 
        break
    elements.append( dic )
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if is_check_file:
    print "check missing files ..."
    for element in elements:
        check_missing_pdf(element)

if is_check_double_file:
    print "check double files ..."
    check_doubles(elements)

if is_check_unused_files:
    print "is_check_unused_files ..."
    check_unused_files(elements)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `checkcites` to get a list of all unused references via your .aux file. To do this simply open your terminal and type:

```
checkcites --unused document.aux
```

[image: checkcites]

Answer (score 10):

Here is an online BibTeX tidy tool I wrote to sort entries, merge duplicates, and enforce consistent indentation: [flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy](https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy)

Also available as a node.js script: [github.com/FlamingTempura/bibtex-tidy](https://github.com/FlamingTempura/bibtex-tidy)

Comment: Amazing script!! Thanks for this, saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

For `biber` users, the bibexport script suggested in @Boris answer does not work.

The good news is that the built-in `biber` command

`biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve <filename>.bcf`

does the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

I have checked out several other scripts that are designed to clean the bib file. In addition to other tools mentioned here, [bibtexformat](http://www.bulheller.com/bibtexformat.html) (try [this github version](https://github.com/yfpeng/pengyifan-bibtexformat) if the link doesn't work)

> Generates and adds the labels (cite keys) to a BibTeX library file, abbreviates journal
>   titles, filters out unneeded items, performs string replacements and checks author names
>   for format errors that may lead to incorrect citations.

And [BibTool](http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/) by Gerd Neugebauer can extract bibliography easily from .aux file.

Comment: I just tried this scrip and it works great! It cleaned a bib file that had gone from papers to sente to bookends and removed all the unwanted crap and formatted it just as I wanted it. The defaults are very good, and it only took a bit of editing the confit file to customize it the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 5):

The python script [BibTeX Check](https://code.google.com/p/bibtex-check/) helps cleaning up a bib file, though doing it not automatically but only providing a list of problems. It points to duplicate entries, missing fields, and inconsistent entries. When extending the script, it may reorder the list of entries or filter only the necessary ones.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

Again duplicates can be very easily handled using JabRef's (I am using 2.10) File --> Import into Current Database. It checks for duplicates and all duplicates can be deselected easily by using "Deselect all Duplicates" button.

[image: JabRef Import window]

All duplicate entries would be maked as "D". Also answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20027/merge-two-bibtex-files/208978#208978)

Answer (score 3):

A totally hackable python script:

https://bitbucket.org/adamhammouda3/bibtools-py

Right now it only sorts items with respect to the bibtex entry key.  My preferred format is
First-Author-Lastname. So it would sort things w.r.t author last name, assuming only that your keys are setup as such.

Comment: The above link is dead now, but it seems that it moved to https://bitbucket.org/adamhammouda3/bibtools-py

Answer (score 3):

A very good way to import the bib file into Mendeley desktop (https://www.mendeley.com/download-desktop/)
Then select the imported references (prior to this you can import them in a separate folder) and click "Update details". Mendeley will correct the bib fields with regards to the online database. Then you can go to "Tools" and remove duplicates. Finally, export the records back to bib.

Answer (score 1):

I only needed to get rid of unused items in .bib file, but many of the packages referenced in this thread were too old and did not work for me or required extensive setup. So I wrote a short command-line PHP script that:

1. generates a new .bib file keeping only references that are actually used in your  .tex file
2. optionally removes some unnecessary fields from your reference file (e.g., URL, URLDATE etc)

To make it easy to use, it runs with [PHP](http://php.net/) (available and easy to install on any computer). If interested, [get the script from github](https://github.com/martinrebane/bib-matcher).

Answer (score 1):

Junxiao Shi has also created a number of scripts to deduplicate BibTeX entries: https://yoursunny.com/t/2017/bibtex-deduplicate/

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth mentioning [this project](https://github.com/FlamingTempura/bibtex-tidy) and its online tool:

##### https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy/index.html

(I found it in this answer: [Merge two BibTeX files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20027/merge-two-bibtex-files/651649#651649))