# Can I nest bibliography files into one another?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, pdftex

I make the bibliography for a manuscript with pdfLaTeX and bibTeX with a call

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{path/list1,path/list2,path/list3}
```

However, I realise that the some articles listed in list2 and list3 could be seen as a subsets of list1, or perhpas there are duplicates, and so on. A little tidying up is in order.

In the body of the text I make ample use of the `\input{}` construct for nesting tex files one into another. I was then thinking that nesting bib files would help me organize my bibliography better. I could express a hierarchy of topics modularly inside one main bib file. I made a naive attempt of nesting in a bib file in the tex way, but to no effect.

Is it possible to nest bib files in a similar way tex file do? 
If so, would someone please give tips and directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only append `.bib` files --- they are flat files by design (at least... I think!), although they have some minimal expansion/macro capability(1).

The best option is using some tidying applications, like [`bibexport`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibexport?lang=en) or [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/). Several options are listed in the answers to [Cleaning up a .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76420/cleaning-up-a-bib-file)

---

Note (1): for example you can say at the start of a `.bib` file:

```
@string{ESP = {\selectlanguage{spanish}}}
```

and then use it as

```
 title = ESP #  {Dictamen del grado de coincidencia estructural ...}
```

Comment: As the chance arises, would you mind it to point in the direction of resources on the minimal expansion/macro capabilities?