# Is there a syntax-checker for BibTeX file?

Tags: bibtex, syntax-checker

My BibTeX file is approaching 1,000 entries. Is there any tool that I can use that will check my BibTeX file for errors in the BibTeX syntax and perhaps help cleanup the file?

Comment: Nelson Beebe has developed a tool `bibclean` that includes a syntax checker.  It isn't new, but neither is BibTeX.  Located on CTAN at https://ctan.org/pkg/bibclean  An article [A Bibliographer's Toolbox](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/beebe-bib.pdf) describes Nelson's extensive work with bibliographies.

Comment: I quite like https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy There is a bunch more resources here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76420/

Comment: biber does checks too.