# Is there a good citation manager for TeXLive like Mendeley for word in Office?

Tags: bibliographies, texlive, windows

I have just started using Mendeley with word and "I like it" is an understatement. So far, the most important BibDesk feature I'm using now is the ability to link the bibliographic entries with their actual order. And when I reorder the cite the link follows it around, too.

I know BibDesk is a good equivalent on Mac for TeXShop. What is a BibDesk equivalent for TexLive in Windows? I hope there is one that has at least almost the same features and also that feature I mentioned above.

(Very similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9454/bibdesk-like-software-for-windows) but a little different.)

Comment: How is this different to the link you've given: the standard cross-platform BibTeX editor (JabRef) is the second-highest voted answer there.

Comment: @JosephWright I wasn't shore it works with Texlive or not. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Mendeley? I'm not sure what you mean about the linking or reordering. Isn't this what happens anyway? (I move citations around and my entries and links get updated. And I just edit my bibliography databases in an editor.) JabRef will work with TeX Live. (Apart from Windows users, pretty much everyone is using TL as there really isn't another distribution for any platform except WIndows.)

Comment: You can use Mendeley with BibTeX output... see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180059/32374